# formatting matrix

Tags: matrix

I have imported a matrix from data file which was generated in Matlab.  The problem is the character (") in beginning and end of every row.  So I can not perform any operation on it.  How to get out of that?

```
  data={{"7.5,9.4215e-06,1.74e-05,1.4433e-06,0,0,0,6.4317e-06,1.142e-05,1.4433e-06,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.9897e-06,5.9795e-06,0"},{"22.5,0.00017399,0.0001583,0.00018967,0,0,0,9.4856e-05,8.6048e-05,0.00010366,0,0,0,6.3507e-05,4.1004e-05,8.6009e-05,1.5624e-05,3.1248e-05,0"},{"37.5,0.00098184,0.0014084,0.00055529,5.5014e-06,0,1.1003e-05,0.00020477,0.00013278,0.00027675,0.0001079,0.00021579,0,0.0005996,0.00095739,0.0002418,6.4078e-05,0.00010243,2.573e-05"},{"52.5,0.0033705,0.0022031,0.0045378,1.7555e-05,3.511e-05,0,0.0012683,0.00078159,0.001755,0.0010903,0.00094689,0.0012337,0.00093512,0.0004276,0.0014426,5.9216e-05,1.1891e-05,0.00010654"}}
```

Comment: @Algohi has a good method to interpret your current format, but I wonder: wouldn't it have been possible to better import the *original file*, so you wouldn't have to do any post-processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(Internal`StringToDouble /@ StringSplit[#, ","]) & /@ Flatten[data]
```